# bitmapimage и image resources

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения

В приложении при изначальном запуске - отсутствуют иконки.
Однако в ресурсах соответствующие Image с заданными ключами присутствуют.

Пример:

```
  <MenuItem Icon="{DynamicResource MenuIcon}"/>
```

Внутри файла App.xaml

```
<Image x:Key="MenuIcon"/>
```

без заданного св-ва Source.

Асинхронно запускается метод, который разбирает xml файл, и задает св-ва Source у соответствующих Image.

Вопросов несколько:

1. Является ли данный подход нормальным? 
   (В плане что существует привязка к объектам, которые потенциально могут не использоваться ? ) Если нет - какой выход из ситуации? Добавлять ресурсы походу получения - это понятно, вопрос как потом задавать привязку соответствующих UI элементов к этим ресурсам.
2. Как организовать что-нибудь аналогичное с BitMapImage ? Который в отличии от Image обязательно требует задавать св-во UriSource ?

Comment: Извиняюсь что запутал. Подправил. Привязка задается в XAML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Что не очень хорошо — это разделяемый UI-элемент `<Image x:Key="MenuIcon"/>`. Попробуйте включить его в несколько различных мест и увидите, какие будут баги. Я бы положил в `App.xaml` `ImageSource`, и написал так:

   ```
   <MenuItem>
       <MenuItem.Icon>
           <Image Source="{DynamicResource MenuIconSource}"/>
       </MenuItem.Icon>
   </MenuItem>
   ```

   Это задаст пустую картинку. А когда вы разберёте XML-файл, положите нужный `ImageSource` в `Application.Current.Resources` (с ключом `MenuIconSource`), и `DynamicResource` подхватит новое значение.
2. `BitmapImage` — это не контрол, это картинка (точнее, `ImageSource`). Вставьте его с ключом `MenuIconSource` в ресурсы. Не забудьте сказать ему `Freeze()`, когда закончите инициализацию.

Comment: А есть вариант задать иконку с помощью расширения разметки ?
Просто везде такие огороды городить не сильно хочется.

Comment: @TorSen: Эээ, а что именно записать? `MenuItem.Icon`? Сомневаюсь, если честно.

Comment: Хм. Замл ругается что ресурс не найден (что вполне ожидаемо) есть ли вариант отключить предупреждение? Или это вполне нормально?

Comment: @TorSen: XAML сам по себе не ругается. Intellisense ругается (так как не видит в проекте такого ключа), но ведь компиляция проходит нормально? Как успокоить Intellisense, я не знаю :(

Comment: Да, с компиляцией все хорошо. Просто спросил :)

Comment: @TorSen: Например, можно положить пустой `ImageSource` в App.xaml, а после разбора XML не добавить, а заменить на правильный.